# Is the next Function in Python Malfunctioning?

Tags: python, generator

As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), the default value is returned if the iterator is exhausted. However, in the following program, the g(x) function is not exhausted, and I hope that the error from f(x) would not be processed in the next function.

```
def f(x) :
    if 0 :  # to make sure that nothing is generated
        yield 10

def g(x) :
    yield next(f(x))

# list(g(3))
next(g(3), None)
```

What I expect:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 9, in <module>
    next(g(3), None)
  File "a.py", line 6, in g
    yield next(f(x))
StopIteration
```

What I encountered is that the program was running successfully. 
Can I use an alternating approach to achieve the goal? Or can it be fixed in Python?

Edit: The program mentioned above may be modified like this in order to prevent ambiguation.

```
def f(x) :
    if 0 :  # to make sure that nothing is generated
        yield 10

def g(x) :
    f(x).__next__()  # g(x) is not exhausted at this time
    yield 'something meaningful'
        # I hope that the next function will only catch this line

# list(g(3))
next(g(3), None)
```

Comment: You use `next(iterable, DEFAULT)` and expect `StopIteration`? Why? Remove the default.

Comment: If a generator raises StopIteration, that means it's exhausted. (The handling [changed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) in Python 3.5 for how a StopIteration encountered inside a generator propagates to the outside, but you'll still never get a StopIteration exception from a `next` call with a default value.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is saying that `g` is not exhausted, `f` is. Therefore `StopIteration` is raised within `g`, and OP expects to see a corresponding traceback. It makes sense, really. If an exception is thrown during execution of a function, you'd expect to get a traceback. You wouldn't expect the thrown error to magically disappear.

Answer (score 4):

`next` with a default parameter catches the `StopIteration` no matter the source.

The behavior you're seeing is expected, and maybe better understood using this code:

```
def justraise():
    yield next(iter([])) # raises StopIteration

next(justraise(), None) # None
next(justraise()) # raises StopIteration
```

Moving to your code - even though the inner use is of `next` without a default argument, the `StopIteration` it raised is caught in the outer `next` with the default argument.

If you have a meaningful exception to raise, you should raise a meaningful exception and not `StopIteration` which indicates the iteration ended (and not erroneously) - which is what `next` relies on.

Comment: This is a good explanation, but you haven't really touched on OP's real question: _"Can I use an alternating approach to achieve the goal?"_

Comment: @ReutSharabani Since the `next` function is catching something unexpected, should Python change its behavior? Or should the documentation mentioned in my question be modified?

Answer (score -1):

`g(x)` is an iterator that always yields `f(x)`, which yields Nothing, and raises a `StopIteration` (in `f`)

You can check that `next(f(some_value))` does throw an exception when called itself.

As will

```
def g(x):
    return next(f(x))
```

But, you've added the default `None`, so that `g(x)` will run, but simply return back `None` since the iterator is exhausted.

---

If you remove the `None`, then you see

```
In [5]: next(g(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-05eb86fce40b> in <module>()
----> 1 next(g(3))

<ipython-input-13-a4323284f776> in g(x)
      1 def g(x) :
----> 2     yield next(f(x))
      3

StopIteration:
```

Comment: "g(x) is an iterator that always yields f(x), so you never exhaust g(x)" - you do, because it's trying to yield `next(f(x))`, not `f(x)`, and `next(f(x))` raises `StopIteration`.

Comment: @user2357112 Is correct. When testing the OP's example without giving none as the `default` parameter it raised a `StopIteration`.

Comment: @user2357112 It's not `g` that's exhausted. `f` is exhausted and throws an exception. It's not really the same thing.

Comment: @Rawing `g` is exhausted also because it sources from `f(x)`, more like `yield from f(x)` in Python 3 (although not exactly the same)

Comment: @Rawing: An exception propagating out of `g` means it's exhausted.

Comment: @user2357112 But if the exception wasn't `StopIteration`, you'd get a traceback. If you modify `g` to `raise ValueError`, it won't be caught by `next`. So no, an exception doesn't mean that the iterator is exhausted. It means that it crashed.

Comment: @Rawing: A generator that has crashed is exhausted. Particularly, it will behave the same as any other exhausted generator on further `next` calls, raising `StopIteration`. (I'm speaking in terms of what happens to the state of the generator, not whether it's equivalent in terms of iterating over the generator or in terms of the `next` call that encounters the exception. The generator enters the exhausted state.)